# Macro Excel 2010 Help Screen Creation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Is there a way to create a help screen in Excel. What I would like to do is be able to have a button that says help. Which upon clicking it will take me to another Excel page for a help document about the page. Then I want to be able to click a button to exit the help screen and return to my previous Excel sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So create a button, then in the *click* event for it change worksheets.  Put one button on the page you want to go to the help page, and one on the help page to go back.

```
Sheets("Help").Activate
```